# Why is my player not moving in SpriteKit when tilting?

Tags: ios, swift, 2d-games, cmmotionmanager

I am trying to using the option of tilting the screen to move my player. So i followed the instructions of Ray Wenderlich and his space invaders tutorial. I just can't seem to figure out why my player is not moving from left to right when tilting the screen.

Please have a look at it to help me out.

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

enum BodyType: UInt32 {
case player = 2
case enemy = 3
}
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let points = SKLabelNode(text: "0")

let gamePlayerSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 16)
let gamePlayerName = "gameplayer"


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


//SET UP FRAME
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)

//SETTING UP Player
func setupPlayer() {
    // 1
    let player = makePlayer()

    // 2
    player.position = CGPoint(x: 240, y: 28)
    addChild(player)
}

func makePlayer() -> SKNode {
    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "block")
    player.name = gamePlayerName

    // 1
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.frame.size)

    // 2
    player.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true

    // 3
    player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false

    // 4
    player.physicsBody!.mass = 0.02


    return player
}

setupPlayer()

motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()

//score label
let points = SKLabelNode(text: "0")
points.position = CGPoint(x: 280, y: 510)
points.fontColor = UIColor.black
points.fontSize = 50
addChild(points)

// setting border around game
let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
borderBody.friction = 0
self.physicsBody = borderBody

//ENEMY SETTINGS START

//repeat enemy spawning
run(SKAction.repeatForever(
    SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.run(spawnEnemy),
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)])))

}
//Enemy settings
func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}

func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}

//spawn enemies
func spawnEnemy() {
    // 2
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
    // 3
    enemy.name = "enemy"
    // 4
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width * random(min: 0, max: 1), y: frame.size.height + enemy.size.height/2)
    // 5
    addChild(enemy)

    enemy.run(
        SKAction.moveBy(x: 0.0 , y: -size.height - enemy.size.height,
                        duration: TimeInterval(random(min: 1, max: 2))))

//ENEMY SETTINGS END

    func processUserMotion(forUpdate currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        // 1
        if let player = childNode(withName: gamePlayerName) as? SKSpriteNode {
            // 2
            if let data = motionManager.accelerometerData {
                // 3
                if fabs(data.acceleration.x) > 0.2 {
                    // 4 How do you move the ship?
                    player.physicsBody!.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 40 * CGFloat(data.acceleration.x), dy: 0))
                }
            }
        }
    }


 func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    processUserMotion(forUpdate: currentTime)
}
    }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you nested your methods by accident? Looking at your code it seems so.

Did you check if the motion code is actually called?

Something like this should work

```
 class GameScene: SKScene {

     let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
         // setup player etc
         motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
     } 

     func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
          processUserMotion(forUpdate: currentTime)
     }
}
```

Also as a tip, I would use optionals (?) when using your physics body instead of force unwrapping them (!). If it becomes nil at one point 
you will crash when force unwrapping.

e.g

```
player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

Hope this helps